# Rotating vertices of geometries in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, geometry, vertices, rotate

I have a great number of area geometries, and line- and point-geometries which have a geometric relation to the area. That means that the distance and the orientation of the lines/points to the areas are important.

[image]

Now I got a new version of the areas and found that their position and rotation have changed! The result is, that my lines/points doesn’t fit to the (new) areas. Distances and angles are wrong.

[image]
[image]

The areas were transformed very individual, so I can’t transform my line/point features with a single transformation. I also can’t use the simple move and rotate functions from QGIS because the line features are often related to more than one area, if I would move it in order to correct the distance to one area I would destroy its geometric relation to other areas.
I can use the really great vertex tool. I select all vertices from the lines which are related to an area …

[image]

… and move it from the corner of the old area to the corner of the new area.

[image]

In this way I would proceed for each area. But the problem is that the vertex tool only moves my points and vertices. The needed rotation is not possible. You can take the line starting at the corner of the old area as an example. It has a 90 degree angle to the edge of the old area. After transformation it should have a 90 degree angle to the edge of the new area. The selected vertices must be rotated around the corner of the area with an angle (in my case calculated as the difference between the absolute angles of the edges of the new/old areas).

[image]
[image]

My question is: Anyone have any ideas how I can solve this problem? Is there a plugin for it or do you have some code snippets for me, which brings me on the way to create an own plugin function or can you pimp the vertex tool?

Comment: Please have a look at the `join by nearest` tool, working with your roads and polygons.